# How to link multiple text views to a single text storage in TextKit 2

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstextview, textkit

In TextKit 1 we have the method `NSTextStorage.addLayoutManager(_:)` that allows to show the same text in multiple text views. This method exists with `NSLayoutManager` but not with `NsTextLayoutManager`.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with TextKit 2?